# Node/JS - class constructor variables undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a simple API in node with pure javascript classes. I'm declaring all my routes in a single file then another one just for the controllers logic.

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const MyController = require('../controllers/my.controller');
const myController = new MyController();


router.post('/', myController.test);

module.exports = router;
```

MyController.js

```
class MyController {

    constructor() {
        this.valueA = 10;
        this.valueB = 30;
    }

    test() {
        // some logic
        // but values from constructor always undefined
        return this.valueA;
    }
    ...
}


module.exports = MyController;
```

but when I tried to call this route on my localhost, I always get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueA' of undefined

If this class is always initialized when call the routes file, couldn't I get the values from the constructor?

Comment: You may need to bind the context to your method: `router.post('/', myController.test.bind(myController));`

Comment: also note that your `post` handling function is, at the least, missing `req` and `res` arguments. It still needs to obey the express middleware signature.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's not required. Express passes these to the function, but the function itself is free to use them or not ;) JS is loose, after all

Comment: I know, but if you don't intend to work with them, wth are you doing using Express? Either you form a response on `res` or you do your work and call `next()`. If that's not your intention, you have no reason to use express.js at all. That's the _whole reason you use express_. Middleware chaining.

Comment: its not a "real" implementation. I just use that to demonstraste the problem more clear. that's why I didn't declare req and res

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is constructed as you expected. However, the method is called without context (the `this`) because you pass the method as the route handler. You need to bind the `this` and there are several ways to do it.

#### wrap the method with a function

```
router.post('/', function(...args) {
  return myController.test(...args)
});
```

or using the arrow function

```
router.post('/', (...args) => myController.test(...args));
```

#### Function#bind

```
router.post('/', myController.test.bind(myController));
```

#### Define the method with the arrow function

*This requires you to use Babel to handle.*

```
class MyController {
    ....
    test = () => {
        // some logic
        // but values from constructor always undefined
        return this.valueA;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked. but it's a bad or good practice what i'm doing?

Comment: glad you found it helpful! I think it's a very common approach.

Answer (score 0):

if the class method `test()` isn't returning anything then add `return this` at the end of the block like so
`test(){

## your code logic here

return this
}`and always remember to use the variable like so`this.variableName` within the block